# What are conceptual open problem in quantum communications and cryptography?

Tags: cryptography, communication

I recently heard that most of the challenges in quantum communications nowadays are related to "practical" engineering implementations and there are no longer "real" conceptual challenges (I mean, of course we could still find open conceptual questions but the main activity is not longer really here in the field).

In order to know if it is the case, I would be interested by having some list of open problems in quantum communications and quantum cryptography that are "conceptual" (i.e related to theoretical physics). What are some important problems remaining to solve in those fields?

I am in particular interested by the interconnection with quantum computing and quantum error correction.

Comment: the way it is currently framed, the answer to the titular question is inevitably going to be: sure. It might also be a bit subjective because different people will/might disagree on what the "main activity" is. I'd suggest to frame the question in the form of something like "*What are the main open problems in quantum communication/cryptography?*". Even better, separating the two fields, because there might be "main open problems in quantum communication"  that are not related to cryptography.

Comment: @glS Thanks. I edited a bit.